# Connecting Sql Server with Docker

Tags: docker, ssms

Connecting Sql Server with Docker giving credentials error its working with the same credentials without dockers but with localhost gaving error Also allowed in Firewall port 1433

```
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "mama12"
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

The Credentials through which am connecting

localhost, 1433
sa
mama12

The error am getting with the credentials are

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to localhost, 1433.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1225)

For help, click: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1225-database-engine-error

---

The remote computer refused the network connection

---

This is my sql server information

`Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19043: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your question.

Comment: @larsks now its done kindly check please

Comment: Are you sure your container is running? If I try to run using your example `docker-compose.yaml`, sql server fails with, `ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is too short. The password must be at least 8 characters..`

Comment: @larsks let me try

Comment: @larsks thanks connected can you kindly tell me where you check error log

Comment: It's just the regular container log, visible with `docker logs`, or visible *on your screen* if you run `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error with sql-server 2022 docker, running on Windows with WSL2.

To connect to the sql-server docker with SSMS (version 19.3), I had to replace `localhost,1433` by `127.0.0.1,1433`

Also not related, but for sql-server 2022 you need a more complex password (8 characters with for example uppercase, lowercase and digit).

Hope this helps.